# Replace characters in an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, replace, character

I am trying to replace characters in an array-string, but it is not working.
Basically you enter a word, then the user has to guess it while typing only 1 character. If the character is in the word the star should be replaced with it.
I can do it with character array, but it should also be possible with string, right?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('#div_letter').hide();
      var word_input = $('#word');
      word_array = [];
      
      word_input.keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){   // if enter is pressed
              
          var v_word_array = word_input.val(); // get the word
          var word_length
          word_array.push(v_word_array); //push the word in an array
          word_length = v_word_array.length;      //get the length of the word
          var stars = "*";

          for(var i = 0; i<= word_length-2; i++){ //create a new array of stars with the same length as the word
            stars = "*"+stars;
          }      
          word_array.push(stars);    
          word_input.val(""); // clear input

       //[0] -> word, [1] -> *
       $('#div_word').hide();
       $('#div_letter').show();
       $('#display').text(word_array[1]);

       $('#letter').keypress(function(e){ //if any key is pressed
          var _letter = $(this);
          var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which); //get which key

       for(var n = 0; n <= word_array[0].length; n++){
       // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        if(word_array[0][n] == char){
          word_array[1] = word_array[1].replace(word_array[1][n], char); //this one should replace a character in position "n" with the "char" variable, fe: "test" -> typing "e" -> "*e**"
          console.log(word_array);
        }  
      }
      _letter.val("");
     });
   }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="div_word">
<label>Enter your Word</label>
<input id="word" type="text"><br>
</div>

<div id="div_letter">
<label>Type a letter</label>
<input id="letter" type="text"/><br>
</div>

<label>Display Array:</label>
<div id="display">

</div>
```

Comment: Just to confirm - this is a hangman game right

Comment: yes, it is the hangman game

Comment: this is easy with an object - if you make all the keys each character with their index included as the value - of the top of my head it should be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am creating an object `letters` which will get all the letters as the key and the value is an array with all the index of the letter in the word.

eg: The word `hey` will have the object like

```
{
    "h":[0],
    "e":[1],
    "y":[2]
}
```

I am using `Array#map()` to create an array of stars.

To know where to put the letter instead of a star I am using `Array#find()` to find the key with the letter typed. If the result is `undefined` - it means that the letter you tried is not in the word. If it is defined, I replace the star at the index of the letter with the correct letter

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#div_letter').hide();
  var word_input = $('#word');
  var word_array = [];
  var letters = {};

  word_input.keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      word_array = Array.from(word_input.val());
      letters = word_array.reduce((obj,letter, i)=>{
        obj[letter] = obj[letter] || [];
        obj[letter].push(i);
        return obj;
      }, {});
      var stars = word_array.map(l=>"*");
      
      $('#div_word').hide();
      $('#div_letter').show();
      $('#display').text(stars.join(""));

      $('#letter').keypress(function(e) { //if any key is pressed
        var _letter = $(this);
        var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase(); //get which key
        
        let keyLetter = Object.keys(letters).find(l=>l.toLowerCase()===char);
        if(keyLetter){
          letters[keyLetter].forEach(i=>stars[i] = char);
          $('#display').text(stars.join(""));
        }
        _letter.val("");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div id="div_word">
  <label>Enter your Word</label>
  <input id="word" type="text"><br>
</div>

<div id="div_letter">
  <label>Type a letter</label>
  <input id="letter" type="text" /><br>
</div>

<label>Display Array:</label>
<div id="display">

</div>
```

Comment: `if(keyLetter.length)` should be `if(keyLetter && keyLetter.length)` because `keyLetter` can be `undefined` when the typed letter is not found. BTW - I don't think this could be complicated like this. Just find the index using `indexOf` method of a string. You prepare an array of `*`. Set/update each element of that array at the found index to the typed char. That's all. So simple.

Comment: `word_array.map(l=>"*");` is too overly complicated. We know the length, so just use `"*".repeat(word_input.val().length);`. Of course by your approach, you need an array (so just append `.split("");`.

Comment: @KingKing `repeat(..)` is also a possibility. I did not think about this. Concerning the `indexOf` You cannot use only `indexOf` if there is multiple times the same letters. Plus, I used the object to store the index to avoid using `indexOf` everytime I type a letter

Comment: There is one thing I don't understand: the "letters = word_array.reduce " function

Comment: well looks like I did not understand the rule of this game. If we need to show all found letters, your approach is OK. The performance in this case should not be expensive. So a `for-loop` may be simpler, and directly solve this problem. (each time pressing a key, a for-loop through all letters will be done).

Comment: @KingKing I just wanted to avoid this for-loop

Comment: @PeterPan Read the documentation about `Array#reduce` this will create an object where the key is the letter and the value is an array of indexes

Comment: because for-loop is expensive??? really??? just try it yourself with a word of 20-30 letters or even more and see how you detect the difference.

Comment: alright, will take a look at it, thank you again, always happy to learn new ways of doing things

Comment: @KingKing I did not say it is expensive. Anyway both way are valid. OP can choose what he needs

Comment: What you did here is doing the for-loop ***once*** (using `reduce`), and each time you still need a for-loop but just through all elements grouped by typed letter (which is smaller in size). If the performance is not an issue - ***always use simple code***. Of course, that's some kind of personal preference.

Comment: @PeterPan you can try this demo instead https://jsfiddle.net/j250ydp0/ - it's much simpler, directly solves the issue. Unless you have a ***paragraph*** with thousands of letters (in which case you need to use the approach in this answer), you can use that simple demo instead.

Comment: i tried both ways in different projects, it is good practice :)

Answer (score 1):

I just turned the word into a dictionary, then used that to determine where in the mask to replace a character.

I have purposely left out the user interaction code as that is surplus to the requirements.

See working [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/TTP5Rw38ILOkItIvphEv?p=preview)

```
var word = "milly";

var mask = '*'.repeat(word.length);

var dict = word
            .split('')
            .map((m, i) => ({ letter: m, index: i }))
            .reduce((f, c) => {
              if (f[c.letter]) {
                f[c.letter] = [f[c.letter], c.index];
                return f;
              }

              return Object.assign({}, f, {[c.letter]: c.index})
            }, {});

console.log(dict); // Object {m: 0, i: 1, l: Array[2], y: 4}

var input = "l";

function revealLetter(input, mask, dict) {

  var ind = dict[input];

  if (ind !== undefined && ind instanceof Array) {
    mask = ind.reduce((f, i) => changeCharacter(f, i, input), mask);
  } else {
    mask = changeCharacter(mask, ind, input);
  }

  return mask;
}

function changeCharacter(mask, ind, input) {
  return mask.split('').map((s, i, o) => i === ind ? input : o[i]).join('');
}

mask = revealLetter(input, mask, dict);

console.log(mask); // **ll*
```

Just used a few map reduces. You know when you need to use reduce, because you'll have an array and you'll want a single value back.

If there is anything you want explicitly clarifying just say - but the logs easily show what happens at each stage.